# Get value return by Ajax without invoking callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm building a simple home made JavaScript framework using CoffeeScript.

In my model class, I have a fetch method which is as follow :

```
fetch : (historyState, callback) ->
  NProgress.start()
  $.get historyState.hash, (data) ->
    (data || data = {})
    data  = JSON.parse data
    if data.success
      return callback data
  .fail (response) ->
    if response.statusText == 'Forbidden'
      window.location.replace '/login'
  .always ->
    NProgress.done()
```

Then in my controller view method, I can use it :

```
view : (id) ->
  state = History.getState()
  model.fetch state, (data) ->
    $('.js-include').html( controller.render 'items/show', data )
```

This works more than fine but, I'm wondering how can I send multiple data to the view?

The ideal would be something like :

```
view : (id) ->
  state = History.getState()
  items = model.fetch state
  categories = model.fetch '/api/url/categories'

  $('.js-include').html( controller.render 'items/show', { items : data, categories : categories } )
```

Right now, I cannot get the data out of my callback from the fetch method so I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery returns a **promise**, when you call $.get, and jQuery will fulfill the promise, when the server responds async.

You can call jQuery like this, if you want the response synchronous:

```
response = $.ajax(
  url: "..."
  async: false
).response
```

Here's the jQuery documentation for AJAX: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Otherwise you'll need to wait, until each of your async requests have been fulfilled.